# Custom view not shown in Horizontal scroll view Not working

Tags: android, android-custom-view, horizontalscrollview

When i try to add my custom view to horizontal scroll view it's not showing.
but same custom view is shown in other layout like Relative and Linear Layout.

```
 layout=new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        l = new PredicateLayout(this);
//       l.sendtext(info);
         for(int j=0;j<info.length;j++)
         {

            LinearLayout aa=new LinearLayout(this);
            aa.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            t = new TextView(this);
                t.setText(info[j]);
                t.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                t.setTextSize(i);
                t.setWidth(screenwidth/2);
                aa.addView(t);
                l.addView(aa, new PredicateLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));

         }

         layout.addView(l);
        scroll.addView(layout);
```

My XML look like this

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

also tried like this

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

    <com.test.app.PredicateLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/predicate_layout"
        >

    </com.omnion.bible.PredicateLayout> 
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

code look like

```
test=(PredicateLayout)findViewById(R.id.predicate_layout);

 for(int j=0;j<info.length;j++)
         {

            LinearLayout aa=new LinearLayout(this);
            aa.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            t = new TextView(this);
                t.setText(info[j]);
                t.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                t.setTextSize(i);
                t.setWidth(screenwidth/2);
                aa.addView(t);
                test.addView(aa, new PredicateLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));

         }
```

Can any one help me.
Thank's in advance.

Comment: if you want to create custom view you need to add the view in layout..

Answer (score 1):

Put your custom layout like this

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <com.test.app.PredicateLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/predicate_layout"
        >

    </com.omnion.bible.PredicateLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```